# multiple images" to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a website where users can upload multiple images. I want to display a specific users images only to him. That means if john logs into his profile, he should only see the images uploaded by him. How can I do this?

Comment: Show us what you have got so far?

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea :

1. Create user logins with distinct loginID for every user.
2. While saving image, in database use 1 column to store location of
   the image as well as another column to store loginID. (LoginID is foreign key referenced from user logins table)
3. While fetching records, use condition like `WHERE loginID = <variable>`